# Unable to assign value to textbox in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing web application in angularjs. I have one textbox and i am trying to bind data using some API's. Below is my html code.

```
  <input class="with-icon" type="text" name="groupname" placeholder="{{ 'Group Name' | translate }}" ng-model="user.name" required my-maxlength="50" ng-readonly="groupname">
```

Below is my Angular code.

```
function getgroupbyID(groupID) {
            var getsavedvechilceUrl = baseurl + "api/RolesPermission/getbyID/" + groupID;
            $http.get(getsavedvechilceUrl).then(function (response) {
                $scope.user.name = response.data.dataAPI.groupname;
            }, function (error) {

            })
        }
```

When the above code runs i ended up in error  Cannot set property 'name' of undefined in the $scope.user.name. May i know hwy i am getting this error? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: show where `$scope.user` is defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

define the user object first

```
$scope.user = {};

function getgroupbyID(groupID) {
    var getsavedvechilceUrl = baseurl + "api/RolesPermission/getbyID/" + groupID;
    $http.get(getsavedvechilceUrl).then(function(response) {
        $scope.user.name = response.data.dataAPI.groupname;
    }, function(error) {

    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use this text box `ng-init="user={}"`

```
 <input class="with-icon" type="text" ng-init="user={}" name="groupname" 
placeholder="{{ 'Group Name' | translate }}" ng-model="user.name" required 
my-maxlength="50" ng-readonly="groupname">
```